# Paradox with muons decay

Tags: special-relativity

I wonder what would happen if muons or something similar would travel at 99.999999999% of light speed. Also, can anyone please shine some light on what happens to the sunlight (photons) and the distance they travel to reach the Earth?

Comment: This question could be improved by editing it to ask only one of the two questions.  It could also use some more details.  Do you have a specific relativistic effect in mind? What is it about muons that you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Well, muons have an average lifetime of around $2.2\mu s$ when they are at rest. However, when they are moving, they experience time dilation due to special relativity. You can think of this, in the following way - if someone is traveling with the muon i.e. the muon appears to be at rest in their rest frame of reference, they would agree that the muon decays in about $2.2\mu s$. However, now consider the observers who are at rest relative to some frame of reference, and the muon is moving relative to this same frame of reference. According to these observers, the muon appears to linger for a lot longer depending on its speed in the observers' rest frame. You can plug this into the time dilation formula, and find out how long is the average decay time for muons according to the observers on the ground.

Comment: @PM2Ring   That is exactly what I meant, but I suppose I wrote it in a rather confusing way. I was trying to say that when an observer moves with the muon, the muon appears stationary to them, and they would appear stationary relative to the muon. Everything else would appear to be moving.

Comment: Thank you NG. Your answer is confusion-free to me. However, I'd like to know if a muon would travel at the speed of light, then will time stop ticking and the distance be contracted to zero?

Comment: @FUA66 In these questions, it is important to know, who is asking the question. Suppose the muon is wearing a watch. Let $\delta t$ be any arbitrary small interval of time on the muon's watch. According to the muon, time is moving at whatever is 'normal' according to him. However, now consider an outside observer. Because of dilation, this small interval has been stretched to infinity. If the muon were at rest, beside the observer, same amount of time would have passed in both muon and observers watch.

Comment: However, in the span, $\delta t$ time passes in the muon's watch, an infinite time would have passed on the observer's watch. That is how much out of sync they are. It will be literally forever ( according to the observer ), before a small-time interval passes on the muon's watch, if it had any. You can also take any arbitrary $\delta t$ for this. Let it be 0.1 s, 0.001 s, any arbitrary time. So yes, time will stop ticking for the muon - or in other words, time interval between two ticks would be infinite, according to people watching the muon.

Comment: Thanks NG again. However, did you notice that Special Relativity (SR) explains the findings of muons on earth in an opposite way, that is, muons decay time increases (dilates) due to its speed. Also, it says the distance contracted for muons to be able to arrive earth surface during their travel. All confusing! I understand it is unexplainable as the thought experiments and unerlying maths by Lorentz and Einstein are incorrect.

Comment: Have you ever asked what c has to do in the Lorentz Transformation (LT) and SR equations as well as in E = mc^2? My learning is that c is everywhere because both Lorentz and Einstein had inappropriate thought experiments and incorrect maths.